# Passing from php to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Is it possible to pass two variables from PHP to AJAX and use them seperately for instance:

fetching this:

```
echo $row['route'] + $row['Distance'] ;
```

which I then can:

```
$.getJSON("DisplayIndividualMySQLi.php", function(data) { 
    // alert(route);
    // alert(distance);
     }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: have the php script echo this `echo json_encode( $row );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them together in an array, which you then json-encode() and echo.

```
$array = array(
   "route" => $row['route'],
   "distance" => $row['Distance'],
);
echo json_encode( $array);
```

or if you want to send the whole $row you can just :

```
echo json_encode( $row);
```

(But only send data that you need for good practice.)

Afterwards you can access the data as data.route, for instance :

```
console.log( data.route );
```

Comment: actually, should only be grabbing the data that he needs. better to restrict further up the chain

Comment: you said "send data", but he could still have a `select *`

Comment: "send data" refers to the data in php (only the needed entries of the $row array), not the data recieved in JS.

Comment: yes, but he shouldnt be selecting data in mysql that he doesnt need. By doing that, he can send the whole result object without delimiting it

Comment: Maybe there are other values in $row stored for calculation purposes prior to sending the json. `$row['secretvalue']` could've also been queried which was then added to `$row['distance']` for some reason. It's not likely, but it's possible.

Answer (score 6):

When you are grabbing data from php with getJSON, your response from php needs to be in json

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

---

### PHP

```
// DB Query to set $row[ 'route' ] and $row[ 'Distance' ]
$sql = "SELECT route, Distance, UserID, RandomField, Etc FROM foo where bar = 'baz' LIMIT 1";
$row = $db->query( $sql )->fetch_assoc();
//...

$array = array( 
    'route' => $row[ 'route' ],
    'distance' => $row[ 'Distance' ],
    'UserID' => $row[ 'UserID' ]
);
// returns { "route": "foo", "Distance": "bar", "UserID": "User" }
echo json_encode( $array );
```

---

### JS

```
// Case is important on things in the data object!
$.getJSON( "DisplayIndividualMySQLi.php", function( data ) {
   console.log( data ); // Object
   console.log( data.route ); // shows php's $row[ 'route' ]
   console.log( data.Distance ); // shows php's $row[ 'Distance' ]
} );
```

Comment: Then echo the data in the javascript with `alert data.route` etc

Comment: tho, personally, i dont like using alert.. I'd personally suggest doing `console.log( data.route );`

Comment: Well its for debug purpose only i guess...? The point was that the output in the question had the wrong syntax, and your answer didn't specify that either.

Comment: yeah, i added that. And either way, i dont like using alert because it locks the browser. Alert is a bad javascript command imo

Comment: Thanks. Also, Could I use this sepecific piece of data in  jquery ajax? $array = array(
   "UserID" => $row['UserID']
   
);